# Get Image using ID from item ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I'm working in a ASP shop with C#, in this case, I'm having some problems while I'm trying to get a image for a detail page of a product, each image for each product. The most important tables are:

Product: which has an image associated for each product with an ID.
Images: which has the images for the different products, one image per product.

The products table contain this field:

```
public List<Imgs> Imagenes { get; set; }
```

And in the Image table:

```
//Id from image
public int ID { get; set; }
//Name of the image
public string NameImg { get; set; }
//Path from image
public string ImgPath{ get; set; }
//FK from product table
[ForeignKey("Product")]
public int Product_Id { get; set; }
public Product Product { get; set; }
```

For getting the data from the database I'm using this method:

```
public T GetById(string id)
{
    return GetById(new object[] { id });
}
```

And in the aspx.cs, where I "fill" the data into the aspx the method is:
(Product manager is the class of the GetById method)

```
prodManager = new ProductManager(context)
Product product = null;

product = prodManager.GetById(new object[] { id });                    
var image = product.Imagenes.FirstOrDefault().ImgPath.ToString();

nameProd.Text = "<h2>"+product.NameProd+"</h2>";
imgProd.ImageUrl = image;
```

The nameProd is a label and the imgProd is an `asp:Image`. The problem is that while I'm trying to get the imgPath as source for the imgProd it says that is null, and I think that I'm missing something about the variable image where I use the FirstOrDefault.

Comment: Probably you should show and inspect with debug this method: `GetById(new object[] { id });`

Comment: If you don't get an exception then `image` can't be null because accessing `ImgPath` on null would error and calling `ToString()` on null would error. Do you mean it is literally the string "null"?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was:

```
var img = imgMan.GetAll().Where(i => i.ID == product.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Where imgMan is the Image Manager to call to the methods for getting data, and for printing the image, the solution is this one:

```
imgProd.ImageUrl = img.ImgPath;
```

Comment: you can simplify your first line by using `imgMan.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == product.Id);`